# How to automatically assign a value based on price range in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have following view with Category (dropdown list) and price value. So,one can easily select any item from dropdown list and put a price and then create a product line. But I want to make dropdown list auto selected based on the price range added by the user. For example, if the price is lower than 100 bucks then it is ordinary, if it is between 100-500, then it is silver, and if the price is more than 500 then my category is considered as gold.

```
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new[] {
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Ordinary"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Silver"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Gold"},
    }, " ◦◦○ Kateqoriya", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cateqoriya, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Price</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is for your `Create` Action?

Comment: Yes, that is for my create action

Comment: You can do it in the get{} of the property Category in the model. you can put your conditions the way it returns the desired value depending on the price property value.

Comment: Following is my model property, how can I put the conditions there?// public partial class Number
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category{ get; set; }
     }

Comment: I am thinking Javascript for this.. so you would want to check the value of the price textbox.. based on that price, change the value in your ddl

Comment: public string Category{ get{if(this.price == 10){return "silver"};} set{value = category;} } for example  ps: you need to create fields.

Comment: I have just tried to add conditions in my getters & setters, but it says not all  code paths return a value

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above I have placed conditions in my getters and setters and it returned the proper values. Thanks for your help. It is much easier to place conditions inside getter and setter properties if to want to return anything. Many thanks.